# Control what appears on standard popover in lightning

Tags: lightning

I have inserted a header component on my lightning contact record page. On this component, account name is a popover. I want to display different fields on the popover. Is there any way to control what is displayed in the popover?

I did not find any such setting in page layout and compact page layout.

[image: sc1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pop-Over field comes from Compact layout in Lightning. It picks the first five fields. See the below image of compact layout:-

[image]

When i hover over one contact in Salesforce Lightning:-

[image]

Another example for custom compact layout on account:-

[image]

[image]

For Account, Opportunity and case detail is also coming along with compact layout fields. These related list can't be customized as per this idea:- [Show any related list on hover in Lightning](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000015AzqQAE)